# Having hard time learning java script coming from a background of object oriented language (See details)

Tags: java, javascript, titanium-mobile

**Some Background Information**

I have been mainly into java development(Java EE frameworks) since around a year , now recently 
I've made to switch  to mobile applications  using appcelerator titanium targeting both android and iOS. It's been around three months working with  titanium and we've released our first build. (It's an In house App)

**Problem ??**

As you probably know , we code in java script in titanium and It's wraps code  into corresponding target platform. Now, my experience with  java script is limited to  writing client side form validation (DOM).and that's it.So I decided to fix it.
Now I started to learn java script by following [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470344725) and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527). and video lectures of douglas crockford.

**Question ?**
Since java (OOPS ?) is bloated deeply in my mind i have very hard time following java script , every thing i see from the eyes of java , (Inheritance , type saftey, exception handling , constructors , instance , static, access modifiers....)
I know java script have support for first class function and  built in Objects  to work with  , however i cant just  differentiate between the two,and when i see something like [this](https://github.com/xavierlacot/joli.js/blob/97a99a08f3d0ed4d13df133ab82ba4c2394a9c69/joli.js) I don't have a clue at first place.

So ,  How to tackle with this situation ?

PS: Though this may be rather subjective but I am sure it would be useful for those whose's having hard time learning JavaScript from oops background.

Comment: those who are down voting , would you mind write the reason.

Comment: Vote to close--vague, ill-formed question.

Comment: I'm upvoting the question 'cuz I don't like when people discourage newcomers. In future I advice you to be much more concise and respect the time of the reader. This was the reason you got downvoted

Comment: @NikitaVolkov  Everything has a steep learning curve , be it put your prospective on SO. and +1 for not discouraging newcomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let me make a point: it's a good thing(tm) that you feel Javascript is so foreign and uncomfortable.  We programmers grow and learn the most by leaving our comfort zone, which is why you'll find countless SO answers arguing that you should learn language X, even if you never plan to use it, just to grow as a programmer.  So as distasteful as you're finding this process, it's good for you, like spinach ;-)

As with learning any programming language though, the rules are pretty simple:

1. Get a good basic language reference.  There are countless websites you can use (but remember, W3Schools == evil/outdated).  As Floydian mentioned there is Crockford's "The Good Parts".  Personally I learned a ton just from my stupid $10 O'Reilly Javascript pocket reference.  And I'm sure there are lots of other great references out there (I'd imagine anything with 4-5 stars on Amazon is worthwhile).
2. Tackle a demo project.  Depending on what book/website you picked they might have a tutorial activity for you, but if not just make up your own and try to accomplish it as you learn
3. Once you have the basics down, throw jQuery in to the mix; it's basically Javascript 2.0 at this point (again, there are lots of great books/sites to choose from, including jquery.com, which has excellent documentation).  Other frameworks are worth learning too (for instance, Backbone is a great MVC/OOP(kinda) framework), but I'd stick to just jQuery and Javascript at first until you are comfortable with jQuery
4. Throw in those other libraries, or other tools like testing frameworks (QUnit and JS Test Driver both being excellent options).  You're getting close to JS Ninja status now.
5. Check out more advanced resources (eg. the Javascript Ninja one by John Resig, jQuery's creator).
6. Go through the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069857/advanced-javascript-interview-questions.  Can you answer all of the questions in them yet? If not, go learn more about that topic.
7. Finally able to answer everything in that thread?  Congratulations: you can now say (in your best Keanu Reeves voice) "I know JS-Fu!"

Comment: Quick follow-up: everything I said was basically true for web-based Javascript, which I highly recommend you start out with (even though you're doing all this for Titanium).  Web-based Javascript came first, and every alternate JS platform (Rhino, Node, WebOS, etc.) all developed *from* web-based javascript ... however, with that being said, I realize you may not want to spend quite so much time on the web-based stuff, in which case I'd recommend ditching steps 3 and 4 and focusing more on Titanium-relevant stuff for steps 2 and 5.

Comment: yes , web based javascript isn't top priority right now , and +1 for mentioning QUnit.

Comment: thanks buddy , I am following those points and let's see .. It wont take long , i guess

Comment: Good luck :-) And while I'm not promising anything, don't be surprised if you find yourself liking JS more once you understand it better.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have asked your question, it feels like you are not looking for an answer, but for a hug.

Personally, I didn't find any problem switching from Java to JavaScript. As with any language, there's a learning curve. Some of the things you've learnt in Java are going to be useful in JavaScript, others will not be. An important thing is to remember that JavaScript has nothing to do with Java apart of part of its name, so try not to make any parallels in your mind.

Comment: I admit that the question is quite verbose , and i know these two are nothing in common but some how , js code is very strange looking at first place and i cant seems to get over it.

Comment: If you want very strange looking - try learning Perl :)

Comment: Heh, Perl's pretty weird, but those parentheses languages like Lisp and Scheme will really make your head hurt (until you "grok" them) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are watching Douglas Crockford, I assume you have read JavaScript: The Good Parts http://amzn.to/JnVgMn

If you have, I think you're doing it right.